# Combine multiple streamed JSON objects into a single JSON object - remove first returned object

Tags: php, json, mailchimp

I've seen the answers to similar questions - but they do not solve the issue I'm having.  So here goes..

I have a response from a MailChimp EXPORT API that looks like this:

```
["Email Address","First Name","Last Name","Source","Open","MEMBER_RATING","OPTIN_TIME","OPTIN_IP","CONFIRM_TIME","CONFIRM_IP","LATITUDE","LONGITUDE","GMTOFF","DSTOFF","TIMEZONE","CC","REGION","LAST_CHANGED","LEID","EUID","NOTES"]
["email1@somewhere.com","","","BORN","",2,"",null,"2015-05-07 15:25:48",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"2015-05-07 15:25:48","74554133","ar5jiewpkc",null]
["email2@somwhere.com","","","BORN","",2,"",null,"2015-05-07 15:25:48",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"2015-05-07 15:25:48","74554137","ar5jiewpkc",null]
```

What I need to do is two things:

1. Remove the first stream object (containing "Email Address" .. etc)
2. Combine the rest of the objects into a single JSON response to pass to a script as if it were a single regular JSON response.

This is a JSON "Stream" that I need to turn into a regular JSON response.

I've successfully turned them all into arrays, but when I try to json_encode the array of arrays, I get back escaped data that is not a true JSON object.

Any help is appreciated!